# wp insert attachment too slow

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have 12,000 posts and I need to generate thumbnail for them. The images are already in the "upload" folder. The problem is that even then the process is very slow. This function is taking too long. Is there anything I can do to make it faster?

```
function Generate_Featured_Image( $code_url, $post_id, $video_id){
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        $path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/save/{$video_id}/"; 

        for($i = 6; $i >= 1; $i-- ){

            $filename = $i.'.jpg';

            if(wp_mkdir_p($path))     $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/save/{$video_id}/" . $filename;

        } 


        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
        $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
        $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
    }
```

Comment: So.. what's the problem? that generating 12,000 thumbnails is too slow and need a way to split them or that generating an *individual* thumbnail is too slow? And what's the `for` for ?

Comment: I would like to know if there is any way to optimize the wp insert attachment. For wp insert post I know there is $ wpdb-> query ('SET autocommit = 0;'); which helps to optimize

Comment: That's done in the db so, yes, you should be able to do that as well.

Answer (score -4):

Do you have a cache plugin and a lazy load plugin ? If you install jetpack (it is free) your are going to have a free CDN.
so the points are:
  1- if not have install cache plugin
  2- if not have install lazy load
  3- if not have install jetpack (it is free) to have FREE CDN

CDN speeds up the site

Comment: your answer to the question does not make any sense.

Comment: No the site is slow, is it needs tuning ? if yes my answer helps

Comment: A CDN is not going to speed up wp_generate_attachment_metadata.